# Import Custom Module in Python [Although it works in PyCharm]

Tags: python, import, module

I see the question has already been asked thousands times, but I'm utterly confused.

- I'm trying to run `hello.py` which import `utils.common` into `hello.py`
  `from utils.common import function`
- And I get the following error:
  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

So my structure is the following:

```
── gig
    ├── __init__.py 
    ├── src
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── hello
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── hello.py
    │   └── utils
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── common.py
```

Provided `__init__.py` in `gig` and in `src` as well, nothing changes though.

P.S. Imports work fine in PyCharm, the issue arises in `docker` container or when I try to run it locally from `terminal`.

Any pointers are very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Giga

Answer (score 0):

usually your full import path: `gig.src.utils.common` should work.